# nose 1.3.4 and logging with custom handlers

Tags: logging, nose

I am trying to have different handlers for different subpackages of my project, however, when I add a console (i.e. StreamHandler to stdout), then due to some reason, the nose is not catching any of the logging output which is going to that handler.

I do not have any special nose configuration except that for every unit test I load the logger as `logging.getLogger(__name__)` and set the configuration of the logging via the `logging.dictConfig`.

So in short terms:

- Expected behaviour: using `--nologcapture` should show all of the logging
- Observed behaviour: there is no difference in whether I use `--nologcapture` or not

Let me know if you want more bagckground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest using [logging_tree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logging_tree) to debug the structure of all the loggers. Just add `from logging_tree import printout; printout()` to see the logging structure right before the console printout that does not work.

Comment: Although this did not solve my problem immediately, but this definitely helped to debug and understand the way logging is configured in nosetests... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have also run into this issue.
`nose` clears loggers before the test and `dictConfig` overwrites any logger configuration. 
This means that if `dictConfig` gets called after your test has initialized then the config is applied after nose has finished adjusting the logging.
This can happen more often then you would expect; imports can lead to re-initialized logger configuration and external libraries might be using the loggers too.

This is not an issue when using `basicConfig` because `basicConfig` does not overload existing loggers like `dictConfig` will.

Ultimately I decided to switch to [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) since development has slowed on `nose` (and `nose2` to a lesser extent). It does a much better job capturing logging output.